# Elmah vs Elmah.MVC Nuget Package - Which to use & why?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah, elmah.mvc

I have Code First MVC 4 application.

I tried installing the NuGet package for logging Elmah - and everything seemed to work fine - Errors were reported fine at `http://myapp/elmah.axd`

I then noticed there was an Elmah.MVC package - so i removed the original one, and installed that. It no longer worked here: `http://myapp/elmah.axd`

I have read in a few places that for MVC apps, you should use the 'Elmah.MVC' package - rather than the 'Elmah' package - but why is this? What would the practical difference be? Is this still the case with MVC 4 sites?

It is strange the original package works out of the box and the MVC one doesn't.

Which should I use and why?

Comment: After installing Elmah.MVC your route becomes `http://myapp/elmah` unless you configure otherwise.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to the Nuget website, you can access Elmah using the url `/elmah`.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC

> Painless integration of ELMAH functionality into ASP.NET MVC
>   Application. Just drop the package inside you ASP.NET MVC application
>   and access /elmah URL. It will also install global HandleError filter,
>   that guarantees all unhandled errors is logged (even if customerError
>   turned "On").

Comment: The [Github Project Page](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah-mvc) link on the NuGet page is especially useful in answering *why* -- Routing, Authorization strategies, and configuration.